# Create a Path from String in Java7

Tags: string, path, nio, java-7

How can I create a [`java.nio.file.Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) object from a `String` object in Java 7?

I.e.

```
String textPath = "c:/dir1/dir2/dir3";
Path path = ?;
```

where `?` is the missing code that uses `textPath`.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

You can just use the [`Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) class:

```
Path path = Paths.get(textPath);
```

... assuming you want to use the default file system, of course.

Comment: Is there a way for this to work with relative path and full path? i.e giving a path relative to where the project or exe is?

Comment: @kuhaku: I think you should ask a new question with details of what you're trying to do and what you've tried.

Comment: @JonSkeet is `Path.get()` is platform independent? meaning that `Path.get("lib","p2")`  will be as `lib\p2`in Windows and `lib/p2` in linux

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya: Yes, it should be fine like that.

Comment: @JonSkeet Paths.get("/opt/path/"); Its returns as "\opt\path\". Can you please provide the solution.

Comment: @DEADEND: Are you on Windows? If so, in what way is it causing you a problem? Sounds like you should probably ask a new question though.

Comment: @JonSkeet. Sorry, i was running on windows. now problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

From the javadocs..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/tmp/foo");
```

is the same as

```
Path p4 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("/tmp/foo");

Path p3 = Paths.get(URI.create("file:///Users/joe/FileTest.java"));

Path p5 = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"),"logs", "foo.log");
```

In Windows, creates file  *C:\joe\logs\foo.log (assuming user home as C:\joe)*
In Unix, creates file     */u/joe/logs/foo.log (assuming user home as /u/joe)*

Comment: I suggest to use `File.separarator` instead of taking care of the current OS. E.g. `"/tmp/foo"` is `File.separator+"tmp"+File.separator+"foo"`

Comment: I guess it does not create the actual file, but it creates a Path object. You can use the path object to create the actual file on disk, using Files.createFile(logfilePath).

Answer (score 19):

If possible I would suggest creating the `Path` directly from the path elements:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:", "dir1", "dir2", "dir3");
// if needed
String textPath = path.toString(); // "C:\\dir1\\dir2\\dir3"
```

Comment: is this platform independant?

Comment: I am fairly sure that yes, it is.

Comment: Doesn't help when the path comes from an environment variable.

Answer (score 15):

Even when the question is regarding Java 7, I think it adds value to know that from Java 11 onward, there is a static method in `Path` class that allows to do this straight away:

With all the path in one String:

`Path.of("/tmp/foo");`

With the path broken down in several Strings:

`Path.of("/tmp","foo");`

Comment: @mat_boy yeah but it's no big deal, really. The method already existed in Java 7, except it was previously called `Paths.get`.