# Configure Spring Bean XML with non-primitive type (java.nio.file.Path)

Tags: java, spring

I can configure Spring beans with primitive values such as String/int/long/etc. How do I get the following to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean class="springtest.SomeBeanTest">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.nio.file.Path" value="/Users/admin/test.txt"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

UPDATE: the following works. The empty list is required for the second varargs parameter.

```
<bean class="springtest.SomeBeanPath">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="/Users/admin/test.txt" />
            <constructor-arg index="1"><list></list></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bean definition XML syntax can instanciate virtually any class.

You can look at the Spring documentation for a complete reference here:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-class, out of which I extracted the following samples.

For example, you can instanciate any class with an empty constructor this way:

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean"/>
```

If the constructor is a static method, you can call it this way

```
<bean id="clientService"
class="examples.ClientService" factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

If you need to call a constructor with an argument, look at:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-constructor-injection

```
<bean id="foo" class="x.y.Foo">
    <constructor-arg ref="bar"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="baz"/>
</bean>
```

Where `bar` and `baz` should be ids of other spring beans. If instead, you use the XML attribute  `value`, then you can use a primitive type directly.
For example :

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
<constructor-arg name="years" value="7500000"/>
<constructor-arg name="ultimateanswer" value="42"/>
</bean>
```

You can also opt for calling an empty constructor first and the call setters on your beans (or mix the two methods).

```
<bean id="exampleBean" class="examples.ExampleBean">
<!-- setter injection using the nested <ref/> element -->
<property name="beanOne"><ref bean="anotherExampleBean"/></property>

<!-- setter injection using the neater ref attribute -->
<property name="beanTwo" ref="yetAnotherBean"/>
<property name="integerProperty" value="1"/>
</bean>
```

There are very advanced configuration options, allowing you to override the way Spring interprets the XML to interpret ref/value attributes.
There is also a dedicated syntax for Maps, Lists, ...
An expression language called Spring-EL in that you can use for dynamic evaluation at runtime inside your XML.
Plus various pre/post processor options for more advanced scenarios (BeanFactoryAware, BeanFactoryPostProcessor, ...)

So, in your case, you could try to decompose like this :

```
<bean class="springtest.SomeBeanTest">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="java.nio.file.Paths" factory-method="get">
           <constructor-arg index="0" value="your path" />
           <!-- Edit: see @clay's edit to the question, the following is necessary too -->
           <constructor-arg index="1"><list></list></constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Note that when there is no ambiguity, the index attribute is not necessary.

Comment: The "get" method is on j.n.f.Paths. The resulting type is j.n.f.Path with no trailing s. The example you give does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no Java7 to test it right now, and I do not know what your class excepts as its argument, but I am confident that the sample code is close to what you expect.
The fact that I use the `Paths` (trailing s) class if because the static method `get` is on this class. This static method in turn produces a `Path` instance which I (can only) guess is the type of argument that your are expecting for your constructor... What kind of exception / error do you get ?

Comment: thanks. I finally got it. I needed to add a second empty list for the vararg parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `String` from configuration file and convert `String` into [`Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) in `SomeBeanTest` class.

You can just use the [`Paths`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) class:

```
public class SomeBeanTest(){
     public SomeBeanTest(String textPath){
         Path path = Paths.get(textPath); // String to Path
     }
}
```

XML:

```
<bean class="springtest.SomeBeanTest">
    <constructor-arg value="/Users/admin/test.txt"/>
</bean>
```

*Note:* Assuming `Users/admin/test.txt` is directly accessed form class-path.

Read more [Create a Path from String in Java7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919501/create-a-path-from-string-in-java7)

Comment: Yes, but this would require that I change the underlying class to use String and not a typed Path...